# How to traverse dom elements in raw JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I do everything in jQuery but now am going back to learn JavaScript proper. So how could I do the equivalent of this in vanilla js:

```
$('ul li a', '#myDiv').hide();
```

Comment: You're approaching this problem the wrong way. Setting hooks via HTML (classes, etc) will better position you for DOM scripting. Don't rely on fancy methods like `querySelectorAll` and `getElementsByClassName`. Both have shoddy support. I've never found a need for either of them.  Instead, simplify your approach to minimize generalities. Surely, there's a better idea than "hide every ul, li, anchor, and this div". In the rare case that DOM 0-2 built-ins and developer ingenuity don't get the job done, consider a recursive DOM search. It's an advanced concept, but very powerful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't rely on [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll). It doesn't work in IE <= 7 or FF 3. If you want to use Vanilla JS you need to learn how to write browser compatible code:

```
(function(){
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

    // Use querySelectorAll if it exists
    // This includes all modern browsers
    if(myDiv.querySelectorAll){
        as = myDiv.querySelectorAll('ul li a');
        for(var i = 0; i < as.length; i++)
            as[i].style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise do it the slower way in order to support older browsers

    // uls contains a live list of ul elements 
    // that are within the element with id 'myDiv'
    var uls = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('ul');

    var lis = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < uls.length; i++){
        var l = uls[i].getElementsByTagName('li');
        // l is a live list of lis
        for(var j = 0; j < l.length; j++)
           lis.push(l[j]);
    }
    // lis is an array of all lis which are within uls 
    //within the element with id 'myDiv'

    var as = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
        var a = lis[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
        // a is a live list of anchors
        for(var j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
           a[j].style.display = 'none'; // Hide each one
    }
})();
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8qvx/2/). Just so you're aware, [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) is another commonly used method of traversal which needs an alternative approach if it's not available (IE <= 8)

Comment: Why can't we re-use code? Why do we have to reinvent the wheel? Just slap on Sizzle to emulate `querySelectorAll` and your problem goes away. And seriously FF3 ? People use that?

Comment: @Raynos considering the OP was asking about Vanilla JS I don't think he wanted to "slap on" anything. Learning Vanilla JS makes you better at using Frameworks too, and able to avoid them entirely for small projects where "lightweight" might be a requirement. It's not that rare.

Comment: you have a point. Sometimes it's better to use other methods then emulating standards compliance in older browsers. It's still worthwhile to feature detect for querySelectorAll as it's significantly more performance (it's in the C++ level)

Comment: @Raynos, forgot to @ you in the last comment :)

Comment: @Raynos Oddly enough, at least on the two browsers I have the Javascript solution seems faster than querySelectAll(). Perhaps querySelectAll doesn't have the best implementation: http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-speed/2

Comment: If the document only has UL elements and no OL, then the UL can be left out of the selector. Also, there is no need to create and array of the LIs and then iterate over the array, just process each LI as it is found initially.

Answer (score 6):

```
var as = document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv ul li a"),
    forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

forEach.call(as, function(a) {
  a.style.display = "none";
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/teEtU/6/)

[`.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.getElementById), [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.querySelectorAll), [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach), [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

This works on all modern browsers and only breaks on legacy browsers (like IE8).

You don't want to do cross browser compliance by hand, you should use a DOM shim for that.

You can use the [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) for `.forEach` support. and you can find a [querySelectorAll polyfill here](https://github.com/kbjr/polyfill.js/blob/master/client/polyfills/queryselectorall.js) which uses Sizzle.

For detailed browser support see

- [can I use querySelectorAll](http://caniuse.com/queryselector)
- [ES5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/)

Don't listen to those guys complaining about browser compliance. Just slap on a whole bunch of polyfills using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and friends and then you can forget about IE!

Comment: Be careful with this; `querySelector` and `Array.prototype.forEach` aren't very widely supported (you need a very modern browser to use this code).

Comment: @CoryLarson lies. It works all all modern browsers and only breaks on legacy browsers

Comment: Well, querySelector is supported since Internet Explorer 8, which could get you in trouble looking at usage statistics of IE 7

Comment: @GNi33 why do we care about legacy browsers? That's what the shims are for. Stop developing for the lowest common denominator. This is the _very reason_ IE6 still exists.

Comment: Believe me, I'm on your side on this one. But it is a fact, that a lot of companies still use Internet Explorer 7 (or even 6, I don't even want to think about that), with no intention to update anytime soon. I hate it, but for a lot of webpages, compatibility for IE7 is a must...

Comment: I'm curious as to why you bothered with `getElementById` if you're using `querySelectorAll`. Why not just `var as = document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv ul li a")` ?

Comment: @patrick_dw because my jQUery to DOM translation missed that step.

Comment: IE 6 and 7 are definitely still widely in use by many corporations, which is why `querySelectorAll` caught my eye as a tad dangerous; but it's really going to depend on who your audience is. If you can use it, more power to you!

Comment: @Raynos: If you're going to be on the soapbox, you might as well include the `"use strict";` declarative too. ;o)

Answer (score 3):

Since a UL element can only have LI as children, the fastest POJS method is to get all the ULs then all the As:

```
function doStuff() {
  var uls = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
  var as;
  for (var i=0, iLen=uls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    as = uls[i].geElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var j=0, jLen=as.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      as[j].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

There doesn't seem any point to a querySelectorAll solution since the above is likely faster, not much more code and will work in every browser back to IE 4.

Answer (score 2):

Good old `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementsByTagName` should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [querySelectorAll](http://www.google.com/m/url?client=safari&ei=Dl1ITpizFoS8qQObioll&hl=en&oe=UTF-8&q=https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll&te=3&ved=0CBQQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEjPQMPwBL47DUbIFQGtv17nnhkPQ) to find the elements, though keep in mind jQuery probably uses extra tricks for compatibility and so this may behave differently.

Then you could iterate over that list (code shown on the NodeList documentation page, linked from the above page) and set each element's `element.style.display = "none"`.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` supports all CSS3 selectors. jQuery does not use extra tricks for compatibility but instead extends the selector API with propietory non CSS3 extensions. (Just like IE did back in the day)

Comment: Are you saying jQuery doesn't support browsers which don't support querySelectorAll?

Comment: Oh no, it does. But that's not how I interpreted "behave differently". Yes querySelectorAll breaks in IE7